# "Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice" from QWidget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt

I'm busy porting an IRC client from Python 2.6 to 3.3 and I've stumbled across a problem with PyQt. The application originally used PyQt4, I'm also recoding it to get it to work with PyQt5 but I'm getting an error without any line references: "QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice". I have narrowed the issue down to a single class.

I understand it's been asked here many times already but I couldn't extract a sure-fire answer for my case so I apologise if my question appears ignorant.

Here's some of the code: http://pastebin.com/Lj60icgQ

Stupid me didn't put the "app" variable just after the import statements when I should've. I then put the rest of the code at the bottom of the main file and I'm not longer getting that error. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Your error message says everything. You are trying to use drawing somewhere, before initializing of QApplication.

Comment: I know it's trying to draw buttons and windows but I'm not sure how to initialise QApplication so it can do that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm afraid single file will not be enough in this situation - the execution flow is not clear just from this one module. The message in question usually appears when you try to use some resources/create some objects that require initialized QApplication - like QIcon, for example.

Instantiation of Qt-based GUI application usually looks like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_window = MainWindowClass()
    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I'll try to use a debugger to find the infringing bit of code in Eclipse as suggested.

Comment: BTW, you created app = QApplication(), but never called app.exec_(), so the app never entered the main loop.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is pretty clear: you are trying to draw a `QWidget` (which in `PyQt4.5` inherits `QPaintDevice` and `QObject`) before you instantiate the `QApplication`. But your code is too large for reading it line by line. Try to isolate the error building a small application and adding functionality step by step. Or use a debugger (IDEs like `Eclipse` + `PyDev` are supposed to be able to debug your app). Or provide us with a small, self contained example of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a QWidget in case you don't need your own custom window class:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QWidget()
window.show()
app.exec()
```