# PyQt: Subclass QTableWidget that shares horizontal header

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt4

I have class CustomTable that's subclass from QTableWidget. I want all instances of CustomTable to share one horizontal header. That means when a header from any table is changed like resized or moved, headers from the rest of tables are changed too. I tried create a static horizontal header variable in my CustomTable class but it didn't work. An error `QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice` occurred.

So could anyone have a solution for this? Thanks for any help!

Update 1:

I still don't have any idea about this. I tried behind code but it does not work:

```
class CustomTable(QtGui.QTableWidget):
    header = QtGui.QHeaderView(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CustomTable, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setHorizontalHeader(self.header)
        [...]
```

Update 2:

My main question is how to create a table that shares horizontalHeader. I tried my way like I said but it's impossible, so is there any work-around?

Comment: Do you have a minimal code that show us what you trying ?

Comment: Yeah, I've added some codes that did not work for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice" from QWidget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383684/must-construct-a-qapplication-before-a-qpaintdevice-from-qwidget)

Comment: @tmoreau No, it's definitely not. I've updated my post.