# QWidget: must construct QApplication Before QWidget python error

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am aware there is various responses to this sort of questions but I havent been able to gage what the issue is as other responses have variations in their question becuase of the code. Sorry if it seems arrogant or abnoxious.

I have created a login window for my booking system which is not shown here as nothing to do with the issue. Now Im calling a function which creates a new window(QWidget) when login is successful but get the error QWidget: must construct QApplication before QWidget. Tried looking for answers but couldn't find any reelevant and python based answers.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
def Login_Window():

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    tabwidget = QTabWidget()

    widget  = QWidget()
    layout = QGridLayout(widget)

    username = QLabel(widget)
    username.setText("me")

    tabwidget.addTab(widget,"Adding A Booking")
    tabwidget.show()
    app.exec_()

class Login_Setup(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        self.init_UI()

    def init_UI(self):   

        self.username        = QLabel("Username -->")
        self.password        = QLabel("Password -->")

        self.username_entry  = QLineEdit()

        usernames = self.usernames_read()
        autocomplete = QCompleter(usernames)

        self.username_entry.setCompleter(autocomplete)
        self.username_entry.setPlaceholderText("Enter username...")

        self.password_entry  = QLineEdit()
        self.password_entry.setPlaceholderText("Enter password...")
        self.password_entry.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
        self.login_button    = QPushButton('Login')
        self.space1          = QLabel()
        self.space2          = QLabel()
        self.progress = QProgressBar(self)

        self.check = QCheckBox("Show Password?",self)
        self.check.stateChanged.connect(self.password_view)

        y  = QVBoxLayout() # Adding veritcal layout. 

        x1 = QHBoxLayout()# First H layout
        x1.addWidget(self.username)
        x1.addWidget(self.username_entry)


        y.addLayout(x1)# Adding H layout

        x2 = QHBoxLayout()# Second H layout
        x2.addWidget(self.password)
        x2.addWidget(self.password_entry)
        x2.addWidget(self.check)

        y.addLayout(x2)# Adding 2nd H Layout

        x3 = QHBoxLayout()
        x3.addWidget(self.space1)
        x3.addWidget(self.space2)
        x3.addWidget(self.progress)
        x3.addWidget(self.login_button)

        y.addLayout(x3)

        self.login_button.clicked.connect(self.login_trigger)
        self.setLayout(y)
        self.show()

    def usernames_read(self):

        usernames = []

        with open('usernames.txt','r') as fo:
            for line in fo:
                usernames.append(line.strip().replace("\n",""))
        return usernames

    def password_view(self,state):
        if state == QtCore.Qt.Checked:
            self.password_entry.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Normal)
        else:
            self.password_entry.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)

    def login_trigger(self):

        self.completed = 0

        while self.completed<100:
            self.completed+=0.001
            self.progress.setValue(self.completed)

        username = self.username_entry.text()
        password = self.password_entry.text()

        self.username_entry.clear()
        self.password_entry.clear()

        verify, hashed = Security.check_login(username,password)

        if  (verify == True) and (Security.check_admin(hashed) == True):
            Login_Page.hide()
            **Load_Window()**

        elif (verify == True):
            Login_Page.hide()
            **Load_Window()**

        else:
            self.progress.setValue(0)
            decision = QMessageBox.warning(self,"Invalid Attempt", "Invalid username and/or password!",QMessageBox.Ok | QMessageBox.Help)
            if decision == QMessageBox.Help: 
                QMessageBox.information(self,"Invalid Attempt", "The username or/and password you entered where not found on the database or hasn't been approved by the admin!",QMessageBox.Ok)
            else:
                pass         

class Login(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()

        self.GUI = Login_Setup()
        print("set")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.GUI)

        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('mot.png'))

        self.init_UI()

    def init_UI(self):
        "----Making the main menu bars and editing--------"
        bar = self.menuBar()

        file = bar.addMenu('File')

        exit_action = QAction(QIcon('exit.png'),'Exit',self)
        exit_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exit_action.triggered.connect(self.quit_trigger)

        file.addAction(exit_action)
        "------------------------------------------------"

        self.setWindowTitle('MOT LOGIN')
        self.show()


    def quit_trigger(self):
        """
        quit_trigger() function desciption!

            Inputs: none

            Outputs: none

            Description: none

        """

        choice = QMessageBox.question(self,'Exit Prorgam',"Are you sure you want to quit?",QMessageBox.Yes|QMessageBox.No)

        if choice == QMessageBox.Yes: 
            sys.exit()

        else:
            pass

class Options_Setup(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()

        self.make_booking = QPushButton()
        self.remove_booking = QPushButton()
        self.edit_booking = QPushButton()
        self.search_booking = QPushButton()
        self.add_users = QPushButton()

        self.make_booking.setText("Make Booking!")
        self.remove_booking.setText("Remove Booking!")
        self.edit_booking.setText("Edit Booking!")
        self.search_booking.setText("Search For Booking!")
        self.add_users.setText("Add Repeat Customer")

        self.init_UI()

    def init_UI(self):

        y = QVBoxLayout()

        self.make_booking.clicked.connect(self.make_appointment)
        self.remove_booking.clicked.connect(self.remove_appointment)
        self.search_booking.clicked.connect(self.find_booking)
        self.add_users.clicked.connect(self.add_repeat)

        x1 = QHBoxLayout()
        x1.addWidget(self.make_booking)
        x1.addWidget(self.remove_booking)

        y.addLayout(x1)

        x2 = QHBoxLayout()
        x2.addWidget(self.edit_booking)
        x2.addWidget(self.search_booking)

        y.addLayout(x2)

        x3 = QHBoxLayout()
        x3.addWidget(self.add_users)

        y.addLayout(x3)

        self.setLayout(y)
        self.show()

    def find_booking(self):
        Options_Page.hide()
        Finding_Booking.show()

    def make_appointment(self):

        Options_Page.hide()
        Making_Booking.show()

    def remove_appointment(self):

        Options_Page.hide()
        Removing_Booking.show()

    def add_repeat(self):
        Options_Page.hide()
        Add_User.show()

class Options(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()

        self.GUI = Options_Setup()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.GUI)

        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('mot.png'))
        self.setWindowTitle("Options Page")

        self.init_UI()

    def init_UI(self):

        "----Making the main menu bars and editing--------"
        bar = self.menuBar()

        file = bar.addMenu('File')

        exit_action = QAction(QIcon('exit.png'),'Exit',self)
        exit_action.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exit_action.triggered.connect(self.quit_trigger)

        file.addAction(exit_action)
        "------------------------------------------------"
        self.show()


    def quit_trigger(self):

        choice = QMessageBox.question(self,'Exit Prorgam',"Are you sure you want to quit?",QMessageBox.Yes|QMessageBox.No)

        if choice == QMessageBox.Yes: 
            sys.exit()

        else:
            pass

Login_Page = Login()
```

Comment: Before calling a widget you must call QApplication, in your case you are calling Login () but you have not built any QApplication

Comment: have you looked into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383684/must-construct-a-qapplication-before-a-qpaintdevice-from-qwidget